# Отправка сообщений через определенно время. Discord.py

Tags: python, бот, discord.py

Как реализовать отправку сообщения через определенное время?
Мне нужно , чтоб бот через определенное время кидал сообщения в канал.

Comment: Попробуй вызывать свой скрипт через cron

Comment: Какое именно время? если небольшое, то можно через модуль ``time``` с помощью функции ```sleep()```.

Comment: Ну где-то раз в два часа сообщения должны будут приходить

Comment: Это не сделать через обычные команды/ивенты discord.py, используйте discord.ext.tasks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как вариант, можете использовать [`tasks`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/tasks/index.html)

```
import discord
from discord.ext import tasks, commands

class MyCog(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self):
        self.printer.start()

    def cog_unload(self):
        self.printer.cancel()

    @tasks.loop(seconds=3600)
    async def printer(self):
        for guild in _bot.guilds:
            channel = discord.utils.get(guild.text_channels, id='channelid')
            await channel.send('Оповещение через каждый час!')
```